# How does $a = 5; $a = $a + 1 ; equal 6?

Tags: php

Can someone explain this code :

```
<?php 
 $a = 5;
 $a = $a + 1;
 echo $a;
 ?>
```

The output is 6,
How?

what did save in RAM?

*$a = 5* **or** *$a = $a + 1* ?

Comment: We don't provide this kind of tutoring here, sorry.  It appears that [you lack the *assignment* gene](https://blog.codinghorror.com/separating-programming-sheep-from-non-programming-goats/).

Comment: Oh come on, guys.  It's a perfectly reasonable question for someone with no exposure to coding to ask.  There's no need to be hostile about it and bury someone in downvotes; just remember, there was a time when you didn't know what that meant either!

Comment: While the question is perfectly reasonable for a beginner it is not perfectly reasonable for this site.  Hence my downvote.  Is it hostile to expect the OP to read the posting guidelines before asking their question?

Comment: I used to have the opposite problem. "What do you mean Mr. Mathematician, I can't reassign a variable?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's interesting.  The teachers he centered his study on must not be all that good.  I have tutored *many* people who start out in the "I don't understand assignment at all" camp, and every one of them joined the "I understand assignment" camp within about 10 minutes (mind you it was a harrowing 10 minutes for some).  Perhaps the teachers are merely assuming assignment is a primitive and refuse to give any alternate models for students to learn it.

Comment: @CortAmmon: Perhaps.  Then again, one wonders how many of these teachers sat down with every individual student and tutored them for 10 minutes to explain assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$a` is a variable.  It should be obvious from the name alone that *its value can vary*.

The PHP interpreter treats variables as symbols, so the logic goes like this:

```
$a = 5;      // set the value of the variable symbol $a to 5
$a = $a + 1; // set the value of the variable symbol $a to the value of $a, plus 1
echo $a;     // write out the value of $a
```

The thing that's happening in the 2nd line is that it's using the value of `$a` in its calculation, and assigning the result of the calculation back to `$a`, replacing the value that was in there before.

As Robert Harvey alluded to with [the link he posted](https://blog.codinghorror.com/separating-programming-sheep-from-non-programming-goats/), research indicates that this is a fundamentally confusing concept to some people; their brains are just not wired the right way for the sort of symbolic thought that programming uses all the time.  If this idea of reassigning values just *doesn't make any sense,* you'd probably save yourself a lot of frustration and wasted time by looking elsewhere for a career.  On the other hand, if my explanation managed to clear it up, then by all means, keep learning. :)

Comment: "If this idea of reassigning values just doesn't make any sense, you'd probably save yourself a lot of frustration and wasted time by looking elsewhere for a career." – For example in Haskell (SCNR ;-) )

Comment: @JörgWMittag Have you read the paper?  It says that recursion is even more difficult to grasp than assignment, and Haskell gratuitously uses recursion all over the place *specifically because it's afraid of assignment.*

Comment: Downvoting this as we should not answer basic coding/debugging questions here as it just encourages asking off-topic questions.